# How can I remove all the duplicate from the links I obtain while scraping a HTML web page?

Tags: python

I am trying to obtain all unique links from a webpage. Below is the code I created. Every time I run it, it says syntax error. How can I please correct it? Thanks

---

```
    uniquelinks = set()
    if links.get startswith 'None':
       continue
    if links.get startswith '/':
       continue
    if links.get startswith '#':
       continue
    if links.get startswith 'https':
       print(links('href'))
       uniquelinks.add(links('href'))
    if links.get startswith ('http'):
       print(links.get('href'))
       uniquelinks.add(links('href'))
```

---

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods to filter duplicate URLs:

example:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
 
pages = set()
def getLinks(pageUrl):
    global pages
    html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org"+pageUrl)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for link  in bsObj.findAll("a",href = re.compile("^(/wiki/)")):
        if 'href' in link.attrs:
            if link.attrs['href']  not in pages:
                #New Page
                newPage = link.attrs['href']
                print(newPage)
                pages.add(newPage)
                getLinks(newPage)
getLinks("")
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, Thanks for for your help. I am going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a comprehension set - I hope I'm correct with `find_all()` function syntax, anyway the idea is to use a set to ensure the unity of the links

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://the-page-you-want-to-scan'
req = requests.get(url)
your_page= BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html')

unique_links = {x for x in your_page.find_all('a')}
```

Comment: `(x for x in ...) ` is a generator comprehension. Set comprehension: `{x for x in your_page.find_all('a')}`

Comment: Oh yes, so sorry... thanks for your correction, I'll edit my post

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `.startswith` then it should be (with parenthesis) like -

```
if links.get().startswith('None'): ....
```

You could try doing that for all other similar lines

Comment: I thank you all for your input. I now get it to run with the explanations I get from you. Thanks a lot

Comment: If this answer works, please accept it by clicking the tick symbol.